# Querying sql database with if conditions

Tags: java, sql, variables, if-statement, querying

This might be stupid question but this code is not working..

```
String sql= "SELECT field, question, choice1, choice2, choice3, choice4, answer "
            + "FROM WineQuiz ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 5";

    Intent i = getIntent();
    String mField1 = i.getStringExtra("FIELD1");
    String mField2 = i.getStringExtra("FIELD2");
    String mField3 = i.getStringExtra("FIELD3");

    if(mField1!="" || mField2!="" || mField3!=""){          
        sql = "SELECT field, question, choice1, choice2, choice3, choice4, answer "
            + "FROM WineQuiz WHERE field='"+mField1+"' or field='"+mField2+"' or field='"+mField3+"' ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 5";

    Cursor c =db.rawQuery(sql, null);
```

What I'm trying to do is simple. I'm creating quiz app, which has SelectActivity sending string data of quiz field into this class receiving it with variables of mField1,2,3.

If SelectActivity does not send any string, the first sql(variable) is put into the query.
If one of the field is chosen, mField1 or 2 or 3 receives string data, then the second sql is put into the query.

However, the first sql querying does not work while the second one works well.
When I use the first sql query independently, it works pretty well. Thus, the first and second sql seems unable to exist at the same time though those two query has no problem by themselves.

Why is that??

Replying the comments, "Not work" means cursor has no data. My continuing code is below, and the error log "Cursor has no data" shows up. It literally means those array does not store any data.

```
Cursor c =db.rawQuery(sql, null);

    if (c.getCount() > 0) { // If cursor has at least one row
        c.moveToFirst();
        do { // always prefer do while loop while you deal with database
            cPos = c.getPosition();
            array[cPos][0] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("field"));
            array[cPos][1] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("question"));
            array[cPos][2] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("choice1"));
            array[cPos][3] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("choice2"));
            array[cPos][4] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("choice3"));
            array[cPos][5] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("choice4"));
            array[cPos][6] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("answer"));
            c.moveToNext();
            //Retrieves whether the cursor is after the last row in this SQLServerResultSet object.
        } while (!c.isAfterLast());
    } else {
        Log.e("SQL Query Error", "Cursor has no data");
    }
```

Comment: What database are you using?  And what does "not work" really mean?

Comment: if any exception was raised, please post the stacktrace

Comment: Are you sure that any of your mField params are not null?

Comment: thank you for your comments. I added some detail above. mField params are initialized as "" in the SelectActivity class, so allo of those params should be "", if I don't select any field in the SelectActivity class.

Comment: Also, I've checked what string is passed to those params with using toast method. All of those params have "".  Then, I tried if(mField1=="" && mField2=="" && mField3==""){...(first sql)}else if{...(second sql)} but cursor still has no data...